# Phonegap Android: jQuery buttons not working when adding jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I have an HTML5 app that I compile as an Android project with Eclipse, loading it from the **/assets/www** folder.

I load some audios using the PhoneGap **Media** class and jQuery (1.8.3), something like this:

```
//Javascript

$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".bt_play").click(function(event) {

            var audio_file = $(this).attr('href');
            playAudio('/android_asset/www/audio/' + audio_file);

            return false;
        });

    });

var my_media = null;

    function playAudio(url) {
        my_media = new Media(url, success, fail);
        my_media.play();
    }

//HTML

<a href="myAudio.mp3" class="bt_play">PLAY</a>
```

The above code works perfectly if I don't include **jQuery Mobile**, it plays the audio file. However, if I include the jQuery Mobile library (version 1.3.1), and without even changing anything else in the code, when I click that link instead of playing the audio it shows an **Error loading page** message.

I've tried using the jQuery Mobile specific function for document ready `$(document).on('pageinit', function() { ... });` instead of the jQuery one, but I still get the same error.

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: Remove `.ready` and `return false`, add `event.preventDefault` right after the click. I also recommend using jquery 1.9.1

Comment: Also, add `data-ajax="false"` attribute to the button.

Comment: @Omar thanks for your reply. When you say "remove .ready", does that mean that I should put the "click" event handlers out there without waiting for any other document (or page, or object) "ready" event?

Comment: You can replace it with `pageinit` or `pageshow`, use JQM events as `ready` shouldn't be used with JQM. Also, are the buttons dynamically inserted into DOM or statically?

Comment: @Omar they're inserted statically. The page that holds those isn't the initial page. From the initial page I call this page (with a regular <a>), and here I play the audios

Comment: Ok, try this `$(document).on('pageshow', '#pageID, function () { $('.btn').on('click', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); rest of code }); });`

Comment: @Omar doing that worked! However, I have to disable all the ajax navigation between pages to make it work. If I don't disable ajax in the links that take to that page (using `data-ajax="false"`) then the pages load in the same "window" instead of a new one, and the audios then don't work. Is there a way to have both? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please update your question with what you have done exactly. You don't need to disable ajax, you can use `$.mobile.changePage('#page-ID');` to navigate between pages.

Comment: @Omar I think I'll have to post it in a different question, the exact issue that I had has been solved (thanks to you). The issue I have now is probably related to something else I'll need to check.

Answer (score 0):

An idea may sound stupid, more tried or put a *pagebeforecreate* instead of *pageinit* or put the call on a function to call in the onclick?

I'm Having a lot of problems with this version of JqueryMobile and I'm putting all calls within the onclick, because live does not work ...

Comment: I tried with _pagebeforecreate_ and _onclick_ and still the same issue... Well, with _onclick_ I don't get an error, just nothing happens

Comment: `live` was replaced with `.on` ever since jquery 1.7

Answer (score 0):

I solved using Omar's recommendations:

- Use `$(document).on('pageshow',...)};` instead of `.ready()`
- Use `event.preventDefault` in the `click()` event and remove the `return`
- Disable AJAX navigation in the links that take the user to this page, using `data-ajax="false"`in the `<a>` tag